# get values from multiple tables based on one foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables, a,b,c,d where b,c, and d have a foreign key pointing to a's id. I want to create a query that grabs all data associated with this key from a,b,c and d. The catch is if b has an entry with this foreign key id, then c won't and vice versa. I have not been able to figure out a way to perform this query in one go. Is it possible in sql?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What's the table schema and desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*
from a left join b on a.id = b.a_id
       left join c on a.id = c.a_id
       left join d on a.id = d.a_id
```

Comment: N.B. per the question, either b or c will have rows but not both.  But it's not clear if that applies to d too.  If not, and if both b/c and d can have multiple rows for the same id, this will return duplicate data.  E.g. if there are 2 b's and 3 D's, that id will get 6 result rows, one for each combination of b and d.